# Eclipse plugin make property value readonly

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-gef

I want to make change in value field of Eclipse properties tab. Since this are directly from eclipse plugin classes. I need the "Value" of type (Domain) should not be editable or it should be combobox [image]

Comment: Is this a plug-in you have written or some existing plug-in? You generally can't interfer with what other plug-in's do.

Comment: its a already written plugin..I am making changes at some other location.in QA raised a concern, since value(domain) information is read-only in the application..so user should not be able to change it from here.

Comment: The original plug-in needs to be changed, it is pretty much impossible to change this any other way.

Comment: its inherited from eclipse framework.